# Why can integer be subtracted from DATETIME but not DATE type

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is the relationship between DATETIME & INTEGER and DATE & INTEGER consistent?

This executes fine:

```
DECLARE @Yesterday DATETIME = GETDATE();
SELECT @Yesterday-1;
```

As does this:

```
DECLARE @Yesterday DATE = GETDATE();
SELECT @Yesterday;
```

This errors:

```
DECLARE @Yesterday DATE = GETDATE();
SELECT @Yesterday-1;
```

I can safely subtract an `integer` type from a `datetime` but not from a `date`.
What is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: The implicit cast from `int` to `datetime` goes back to Sybase days. I guess for the new datatypes they decided not to do this as a possible cause of bugs (accidentally inserting integer values into a `datetime` column and not being alerted to the issue). A related Connect Item request complaining about implicit conversions [Add optional checks for more robust development](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=260762)

Comment: @MartinSmith - did you vote to close? whoever did hasn't left any comment; nice to see a comment as it gives the possibility of amending the OP

Comment: No I haven't voted to close. Both are off topic votes. One for migration to [dba.se] and one straight off topic. I was considering "not constructive" though as only Microsoft can tell you the definitive reason for the design decision.

Comment: @MartinSmith - I've edited the explicit reference to MS out of the question now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, it is very consistent. `DATETIME` is a type inherited from previous editions of SQL Server. Since 2008 edition, `DATETIME2` has been introduced, and possibility of adding/subtracting integers removed. You can still do it on `DATETIME` as a legacy.

`DATE`, like `DATETIME2` had been around since 2008, too, and for this type adding/subtracting numbers is also prohibited.

This gives you an error:

```
DECLARE @Yesterday DATETIME2 = GETDATE();
SELECT @Yesterday-1;
```

So everything's fine.

Answer (score 1):

So this might be better:

```
declare @Yesterday DATE = DATEADD(d, -1, getdate())
select @Yesterday
```

Comment: - +1 thanks for info - there are lots of workarounds - I just wondered "why?"