# Why is the addition operator defined for DATETIME values but not for DATE?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I am aware that the workaround is to use `DATEADD` for both data types. I'd like to understand why the language designers chose to define this operator for one data type but not the other?

When you try using the plus operator directly on a `DATE`

```
DECLARE @tomorrow DATE = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) + 1
```

you get this error message:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

However you can add an integer to a `DATETIME`, and you can implicitly convert that `DATETIME` to a `DATE` with no errors:

```
DECLARE @thisTimeTomorrow DATETIME = GETDATE() + 1
DECLARE @tomorrow DATE = GETDATE() + 1
```

Comment: Don't use the `+ 1` - what do you really add? 1 hour? 1 day? 1 year? Use the more appropriate `DATEADD()` method which allows you to clearly state what you're adding - millisecond through year .....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can integer be subtracted from DATETIME but not DATE type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569817/why-can-integer-be-subtracted-from-datetime-but-not-date-type)

Comment: The language designers probably had to put the addition operator there for compatibility reasons - maybe with Oracle (or perhaps something that Oracle also decided to copycat - Sybase, DB2, who knows). There was no reason to do that for `date`, since it's relatively recent; removing it from `datetime` is not an option anymore, of course.

Comment: @marc_s "Don't use the + 1 - what do you really add? 1 hour? 1 day? 1 year?" It's interesting that the answer to that is one day, I would have wrongly guessed 1 millisecond.

Comment: Unless the SQL Sever development team has made an official post about this question, I would say it can only attract speculative answers.

Answer (score 4):

This is because SQL Server DATETIME behaviour is kept the same for compatibility purposes. Since version 2008 DATETIME2 was introduced, that prohibits the ability to add integers, DATE was also introduced at the same time, and this also prohibits addition.

The simplest solution would be to move the addition inside the CONVERT:

```
DECLARE @tomorrow DATE = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() + 1)
```

Although I would recommend using DATEADD rather using integer additions:

```
DECLARE @tomorrow DATE = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DD, +1, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: `DATE` is stored as 1, 3-byte integer not as `NTEXT`. check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb630352.aspx)

Comment: Thanks ughai. We learn something new everyday. The premise is still the same, the integer addition must be moved inside the CONVERT operation.

Comment: I've edited my answer after a bit of research into the issue. It seems DATETIME is for all intensive purposes "depracated", but is kept for legacy code issues. DATETIME2 is the official datetime object in SQL Server since 2008 and should be used, but I've never used it myself to be honest. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft SQL Server originated from the Sybase code base where an addition operator can combine datetime with a numeric and yield a datatime.  According to the ANSI SQL standard, the result of such an expression should yield an interval type (which doesn't exist in SQL Server).

The newer time, date, datetime2, datetimeoffset data types developed by Microsoft intentionally do not support this legacy behavior in favor of ANSI standards.  The built-in DATEADD function must be used.